# string format getting changed in excel

Tags: c#-3.0

string StrDate= Convert.ToDateTime(Datset.Tables[0].Rows[i][j]).ToString(@"dd-MM-yyyy").Trim();
string StrDateNew=StrDate.ToString();
strmWriteText.Write(StrDateNew.ToString());

when i write the  data to  excel file  the string format is getting chaged  into 
 dd/mm/yyyy

is there any way i can solve this problem i am using excel 2000,vs 2003

any help would great 
 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to deal with the Range.[NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa253102%28office.10%29.aspx) property while you write the data to Excel.
e.g. the following line where format `myWorkSheet` *column 1* to "dd-MM-yyyy":

```
myWorkSheet.get_Range(myWorkSheet.Cells[1,1],myWorkSheet.Cells[Datset.Tables[0].Rows.Count+1,1]).NumberFormat="dd-mm-yyyy";
```